# TableView repeats first 13 rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an UITableView with 30 objects.
Controller shows correctly first 13 rows, on 14th row use a "joker" row which changes his content scrolling, then start again with first thirteen row and "joker" row until the end.

That's code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView * flagImageView = (UIImageView *) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel * nationLabel = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:2];

    nationLabel.text = [_nationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    nationLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);

    return cell;
}
```

Strange thing is that configuring cell in `if (cell == nil) { ... }` it doesn't work...

Comment: What is "joker" row? Could you please show other parts of your controller?

Comment: Is a row which shows row which is loading..it's hard to explain and very strange thing; if you're using xCode 5 DP, down, I posted code

Comment: I am wondering why you are getting 13 rows. you are doing nothing with your cell..!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Change your code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell"];
            if(cell == nil)
            {
               cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];      
            }

            UIImageView * flagImageView = (UIImageView *) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
            UILabel * nationLabel = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:2];

            nationLabel.text = [_nationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            nationLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

            NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);

            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! What's all? (in [UITableViewCell ALL]initWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];)

Comment: where u are using the cell in your method provide full code, in your code just creating and returning the cell..

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the nationLabel. When I replaced

```
UILabel * nationLabel = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:2];

nationLabel.text = [_nationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [_nationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

it's working fine (at least the text). So I think you should try to make a UITableViewCell subclass, make property for that label and see if it's ok then.

Comment: it works because it types number in default label of cell style, it doesn't use my label in storyboard so, using the UIIMageView in storyboard, it won't be showed...

Comment: it works in the default label, so I guess the problem has to be in the viewWithTag way to get the label (Actually this is the first time I see someone gets a cell label through tableView viewWithTag). If it's made the standard way - subclassing UITableViewCell and making properties, it's working fine.